# How to use same elements of same model in yii?

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii.. I am developing a form in which i am having a registration form in which i need to get education details of a student. It includes

```
                'Post Graduation',
                'Graduation' and 
                'Schooling'
```

details. Each of this will be having pass year, qualification etc fields.

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'user_id' => 'User',
            'qualification_id' => 'Qualification',
            'specialization_id' => 'Specialization',
            'pass_year' => 'Pass Year',
            'university_id' => 'University',
            'duration_from' => 'Duration From',
            'duration_to' => 'Duration To',
            'percentage_marks' => '% of Marks / GPA',
            'course_type_id' => 'Course Type',
            'awards' => 'Awards & Scholarships',
        );
    }
```

How can i use the same model to create similar elements to get these details separately for

```
                'Post Graduation',
                'Graduation' and 
                'Schooling'
```

I tried by creating different objects for the model and including them in the form.

```
    $postGraduate = new CandidateQualification;
    $graduate = new CandidateQualification;
    $preGraduate = new CandidateQualification;
```

But this create problem as all of them will be having same name and validation also wont help. Please provide any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yii scenarios? http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [scenario`s](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/) Luke.

> Scenarios are an extremely useful tool for separating validation tasks on any class you use derived from CModel. In this tutorial we will use CActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

For this Specific task you need to use scenarios as others have mentioned.[Understanding Scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/). Once you have these defined in your `model` all you need is to create instance of classes with required scenario

for example you can do

```
$studentModel = new student('pregrad');
$studentModel = new student('grad');
$studentModel = new student('postgrad');
```

and when ever form is rendeded using same `$studentModel` validations would be different